# How do I find tablespace names

Tags: oracle-apex

I'm trying to upgrade APEX from oracle XE 11.2 to APEX 5.1.2

I'm an absolute newbie on databases. I know almost nothing, and I'm doing this to learn.

I had just installed OracleXE112_Win64, and I don't know how to find the data to do the upgrade.

To do the upgrade, I need this data:

-tablespace_apex is the name of the tablespace for the Oracle Application Express application user.

-tablespace_files is the name of the tablespace for the Oracle Application Express files user.

-tablespace_temp is the name of the temporary tablespace or tablespace group.

-images is the virtual directory for Oracle Application Express images. To support future Oracle Application Express upgrades, define the virtual image directory as /i/.

How do I find what is tablespace_apex, tablespace_files, tablespace_temp, and images directory?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Officially there APEX 5.1 is not supported in Oracle XE but here you can find a guide to help you with that
https://mikesmithers.wordpress.com/2015/05/25/upgrading-to-apex-5-on-oracle-xe-11g/

In general to look at the tablespace names you can use

```
SELECT TABLESPACE_NAME FROM DBA_TABLESPACES;
```

I strongly suggest to create new tablespaces for the new installation of Apex and to use TEMP as tablespace_temp.

The virtual image directory is the URL for your images, so if you don't have any specific requirements just use the default /i/